# Run command as Linux "system" user (shell = /bin/false)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, cron, su

I created a "system" user in Ubuntu 11.04 (`adduser --system`) for running certain cron jobs, but sometimes I want to test things out by manually running commands as that user. What's the easiest way to do this?

`su` doesn't work, because the user has `/bin/false` as its shell (which is fine for cron). I've been manually changing the shell to `/bin/bash` to do my testing and then changing it back again, but I wonder is there an easier way?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I use `su - targetuser -s /bin/bash` from a root shell.

For direct command execution use `-c`:

```
su - targetuser -s /bin/bash -c "/bin/echo hello world"
```

Comment: That works, thanks! How did I miss the -s option?

Comment: you can also tack on a -c "your_command_here" option to pass the command you'd like to run versus waiting for the shell and then typing it at a new prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Use sudo.  This will work even if the user doesn't have a real shell.